# Getting the response code of an HTTP request - Java

Tags: java, rest, http

Here my problem: I want to get the response code of an HTTP request made by the client.

This is my code:

```
@GET
@Produces({MediaType.TEXT_XML,  MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON ,  MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
public List<Person> getPersonsBrowser() throws IOException {

    int code = 0;
    try
    {
        URL url = new URL(uriInfo.getAbsolutePath().toString());
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.connect();

        code = connection.getResponseCode();  

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }

    System.out.println("code: "+code);
    System.out.println("Request #1: "+ request.getMethod() + " /"+uriInfo.getPath() + "Accept: ");

    //System.out.println("Getting list of people...");
    List<Person> people = Person.getAll();

    //System.out.println("----"+people.get(1));
    return people;
}
```

My problem is that the result is an infinite loop, like this:

```
> Request #1: GET /personAccept: 
code: 200
Request #1: GET /personAccept: 
code: 200
Request #1: GET /personAccept: 
code: 200
Request #1: GET /personAccept: 
code: 200
Request #1: GET /personAccept: 
code: 200
Request #1: GET /personAccept: 
code: 200
Request #1: GET /personAccept: 
code: 200
Request #1: GET /personAccept: 
code: 200
Request #1: GET /personAccept: 
code: 200
```

This is the method "getAll" of the class "PersonModel.java":

```
@NamedQuery(name="Person.findAll", query="SELECT p FROM Person p")

        public static List<Person> getAll() {
        EntityManager em = LifeCoachDao.instance.createEntityManager();
        List<Person> list = em.createNamedQuery("Person.findAll", Person.class)
            .getResultList();
        LifeCoachDao.instance.closeConnections(em);
        return list;
    }
```

How can I avoid this loop? How could I get the code without this loop?

Comment: Once you fix this problem, you should have a look at that `try-catch` block. You don't want to be silently swallowing exceptions like that.

Comment: What is the code for `Person.getAll()`

Comment: Why is this tagged as JPA question? Looks like more of a REST/JAX-RS problem.

Comment: Why are you making a request to the exact same endpoint from inside the endpoint? Makes no sense. That's why you are getting an infinite loop. What exactly are you trying to acheive?